# Develop Davinci Resolve plugin

Tags: video-editor, davinci-resolve, plugins

I need to develop plugin for Davinci Resolve. This plugin must be similar on Premiere Plugin, which can be active in the separate panel (please see screenshot).

In Premiere Pro I can write this panel on the next technology stack: js/ts+html+css+Adobe CEP(platform to interact with Adobe API).

I'm new to Davinci Resolve. Tell me the entry point in Davinci Plugin Developing.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Can you please edit the question and explain it more clearly?

Comment: @Matt Hello! I edited my question

Comment: Blackmagic have a developer page and there's links to the forum there: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/ae/developer/ you might get better answers than on this site.

Comment: Ok, thank you @stib

Answer (score 2):

From DaVinci Resolve you can go to Help -> Documentation -> Developer. It will open the folder with available development options for DaVinci Resolve. In linux it is in `/opt/resolve/Developer/Scripting/README.txt`
Some of types of plugins are: python/lua scripting, OpenFX plugins, Electron integrations, Fusion, Codec plugins, lut.

Explore files, there are examples there. And you can start programming.